# How can we see the transformed vaue z, in autoencoder link: http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/dA.html

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, theano

How can we see the z value , which is the reconstruction of x (dataset )

Please see the link : http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/dA.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function "get_reconstructed_input" will return a Theano variable that represent z from the hidden representation. Check the function "get_cost_updates" It use it to train the model.

```
   tilde_x = self.get_corrupted_input(self.x, corruption_level)
   y = self.get_hidden_values( tilde_x)
   z = self.get_reconstructed_input(y)
```

If you don't want to train the model, you can do this:

```
   y = self.get_hidden_values(self.x)
   z = self.get_reconstructed_input(y)
```

To make an executable function that compute this:

```
f = theano.function([x], z)
```

Comment: consider my data size is 10000 X 31 and hidden layer is of 20 neurons, so after training i get w,b,b_prime. With these values       
y = T.nnet.sigmoid(T.dot(data, w) + b)
z = T.nnet.sigmoid(T.dot(y, numpy.transpose(w)) + b_prime)
f = theano.function([],z). Thus i get reconstructed value from the function f. Am I doing it correctly, if so for sda i have to follow the same approach.